# Emacs: mark contents as type image in copy to clipboard

Tags: images, clipboard, pdf-tools

When using pdf-tools (https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) I'd like to be able to select and area and copy it to the clipboard as an image, so as to insert into other applications. Selecting is easy from pdf-tools, but pasting into other applications as image does not work.

It seems that for this to be possible, Emacs would have to mark the contents of the selected area as being of type image [pdf-tools: issue 184](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/184#issuecomment-238947452). Is such a thing even possible?