# How can I yank images from Emacs?

Tags: osx, copy-paste, images, yank, inline-image

I want to copy images from Emacs to macOS clipboard. I have tried selecting them and yanking, which hasn't worked. Google also didn't have a solution.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but a similar question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26418/emacs-mark-contents-as-type-image-in-copy-to-clipboard

Comment: @Dan I want to copy the image files to macOS clipboard. I have tried selecting the image and pressing 'y'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very rudimentary function that will yank the displayed image at point to the X11 clipboard:

```el
(defun x11-yank-image-at-point-as-image ()
  "Yank the image at point to the X11 clipboard as image/png."
  (interactive)
  (let ((image (get-text-property (point) 'display)))
    (if (eq (car image) 'image)
        (let ((data (plist-get (cdr image) ':data))
              (file (plist-get (cdr image) ':file)))
          (cond (data
                 (with-temp-buffer
                   (insert data)
                   (call-shell-region
                    (point-min) (point-max)
                    "xclip -i -selection clipboard -t image/png")))
                (file
                 (if (file-exists-p file)
                     (start-process
                      "xclip-proc" nil "xclip"
                      "-i" "-selection" "clipboard" "-t" "image/png"
                      "-quiet" (file-truename file))))
                (t
                 (message "The image seems to be malformed."))))
      (message "Point is not at an image."))))
```

### Requirements

You need to have `xclip` installed.

### Limitations

1. Only works on a system with X11 (i.e. won't easily work on MacOS, Windows etc.). Unfortunately, it seems that `pbpaste`, which is usually a drop-in replacement for `xclip` cannot copy an image to the clipboard. For possible workarounds, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919403/set-clipboard-to-image-pbcopy). I don't have access to a MacOS system, so I can't apply these myself.
2. `xclip` cannot currently copy to multiple targets/atoms ([github issue](https://github.com/astrand/xclip/issues/32)), so programs that can't deal with the `image/png` target atom, will either ignore the paste from the clipboard or insert the image as binary "text".
3. (Relatively easily circumventable.) Currently, the atom used is `image/png` irrespective of whether the image is actually a `png` or not. However, it seems that the programs that can deal with an "image" target atom (such as `gimp` or `inkscape`) seem to (somehow) correctly deal with the paste, even if the image was not a `png`. If needed, this could be circumvented by first inspecting the image type and selecting the target atom based on that.

### Miscellaneous

#### Region

For a region, `(get-text-property (text-property-not-all (point-min) (point-max) 'display nil) 'display)` would get you the first image (or other "special" `display` property) in the region. The other [property search functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Property-Search.html) might also be helpful.

#### Debugging `:data`

Try:

```
(let ((data (plist-get
             (cdr (get-text-property (point) 'display))
             ':data))
      (coding-system-for-write 'no-conversion))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert data)
    (save-buffer)))
```

(you will be prompted about the location where to save).

Comment: Thanks! I made it work in macOS. I will post it as another answer.

Comment: This only works when the point is exactly before the image. How can I make it work for regions? Or when the point is after the image?

Comment: When data is not nil, this doesn't work in macOS.

Comment: I have done some testing for the data case, using pbcopy instead of impbcopy. Running 'pbpaste > t.jpg' results in a corrupt file. Here is the data variable: https://gist.github.com/NightMachinary/2c67957b1aa8261679d9d973a5f6366a

Comment: I've edited the answer with some suggestions. I've also made it into a "community wiki" so you can change it, if you want. Looking at the data in the gist, it does indeed seem to be corrupt, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

From @aplaice's answer, adapted to macOS:

```
(defun ns-yank-image-at-point-as-image ()
    "Yank the image at point to the X11 clipboard as image/png."
    (interactive)
    (let ((image (get-text-property (point) 'display)))
      (if (eq (car image) 'image)
          (let ((data (plist-get (cdr image) ':data))
                (file (plist-get (cdr image) ':file)))
            (cond (data
                   (with-temp-buffer
                     (insert data)
                     (call-shell-region
                      (point-min) (point-max)
                      "impbcopy")))     ;; http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=3816 Linux x11: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41016/how-can-i-yank-images-from-emacs?noredirect=1#comment64407_41016
                  (file
                   (if (file-exists-p file)
                       (start-process
                        "_" nil "impbcopy"  (file-truename file))))
                  (t
                   (message "The image seems to be malformed."))))
        (message "Point is not at an image."))))
```